# jquery $.post not working in ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post

I'm having a problem sending data back by $.post.
This is my JS code for $.post :

```
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
$.post(
    "run.php",
    { q: cmd , dir: dir },
    function(data, status){
        $("#results").html(data);
    }
);
```

and in run_php :

```
// I run python code using q and dir. It works fine.
foreach ($fileArr as $key => $value) {
    echo '<p><a href="'.$default_dir.'/'.$value.'" target="_blank">'.$value.'</a></p>';
}
// But here it doesn't return any value.
```

It works in Chrome and Firefox, not in IE. What could be the problem?
This code is so simple but I'm struggling for hours.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the console for any errors, or to see what the returned reponse is?

Comment: If you're using jQuery what version of it are you using? Newer versions drop some IE

Comment: When I added .fail to the .post, xhr.responseText was empty.

Comment: I'm using jquery 1.10.2 @AndyHolmes

Comment: Ah then yeah you need to use 1.9 as the newer versions have dropped some ie versions

Comment: I used 1.9.1 version but it's not working. (ie version is 10.) Could it be any other issue ? like datatype or ... should I try .ajax or .get?

Comment: @AndyHolmes - No, the 1.x stream still supports older IE, but the 2.x stream doesn't.

Comment: Have you tested your selector `$("#results").html('foo')`? IE have another behavior (if you compare with FF or Chrome) - if your project has a global var with name `results` you must have problems...

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery 1.9 version` for `IE` as the latest version of jquery not supporting `IE<=9`

Read [jquery 2.0 release](http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/)

Comment: The OP says that he's using 1.10.2 so this isn't the problem (I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: i am not downvoter. but i want to know why jquery 1.10 not supported below IE version. all jquery 1.x will support lower version of IE browsers right ? only jquery 2.0 not supports below version of IE9

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this is incorrect - or at best incomplete. The 1.x stream (currently up to 1.11.0) supports older IE. The 2.x stream (currently 2.1.0) doesn't support older IE. The latest 1.x has the same API as the latest 2.x.

Comment: @Vucko your are right. only jquery 2.0 not supports lower versions of IE.